# Подскажите где ошибка в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin, recyclerview.adapter

Недавно начал изучать `RecyclerView`. Создал свой адаптер - `MyAdapter`, который принимает `ArrayList<String>`. В MainActivity вроде всё передал адаптеру, но при запуске на телефоне `RecyclerView` пустой. Пытался разместить `ArrayList` в `MyAdapter`, но ничего не изменилось.

MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var layoutmanger: LinearLayoutManager
    private lateinit var myAdapter: MyAdapter
    val arrayL: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf("one","two","three")

    private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_news)
        layoutmanger = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        myAdapter = MyAdapter(arrayL)

        recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter
    }
}
```

MyAdapter:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MyAdapter(private val arrayData:ArrayList<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        val context = parent.context
        val layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.test_adapter 
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)                                                                   
        val view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, parent, false)
        return ItemViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrayData.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.setData(arrayData[position])
    }

    class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text)
        fun setData(str: String){
            title.text = str
        }

    }

}
```

XML элемента для MyAdapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="24dp">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

XML с RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_news"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Где я ошибся? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не вижу где вы передаете `LayoutManager` в `RecyclerView`, полагаю в этом и ошибка